# There is any way to get wave motion on specific object

Tags: animation

[image: I want some wave animation (loop)]

**Looking for creating a wave effect from bottom to up in loop and in form of that object**

**I try with wave modifier but it did not work well**

Comment: you need a lot of geometry to make the wave modifier look good. Did you try subdividing your model before e.g. with a subdivision modifier before the wave modifier? try increasing level and watch the difference. if that doesn't work, pls provide your blend file. thx.

Comment: @Chris , actually first I model a object in this wave type but now I need a animation over it wait I'm sharing file so you can understand better

Comment: @Chris [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13gGg30r4s6ixiYULo5GyF-avrmAP0WvA/view?usp=sharing) Thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not show us how it should look like, so a link to an animation/video how it should look like would help a lot.

Here i made a gif for you so that you can see how important the geometry is:

[image]

As you can see, the more subdivision it has, the better it looks.

Comment: Thank you @Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can create this kind of mesh:

[image]

Give it a *Wave* modifier (on Y only so that it's unidirectionnal) and a *Lattice* modifier (in order to narrow it at its bottom):

[image]

Adjust the *Speed* of the *Wave* modifier:

[image]